# Qt5 menubar's action with text "Exit" just disappear

Tags: qt

I was trying to write a QT application inherit from QMainWindow class.
I use Qt's ui to write a menubar with three Action:*Open Close Exit*.

The configuration of each Action looks same, but the last one just disappear.

[image]

[image]

By the way, the generated ui_mainwindow.h is:

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QAction *actionOpen;
    QAction *actionClose;
    QAction *actionExit;
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QTextBrowser *textBrowser;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QMenu *menuFile_2;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(400, 300);
        actionOpen = new QAction(MainWindow);
        actionOpen->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("actionOpen"));
        actionClose = new QAction(MainWindow);
        actionClose->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("actionClose"));
        actionExit = new QAction(MainWindow);
        actionExit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("actionExit"));
        centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget);
        horizontalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout"));
        textBrowser = new QTextBrowser(centralWidget);
        textBrowser->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textBrowser"));

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(textBrowser);

        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 22));
        menuFile_2 = new QMenu(menuBar);
        menuFile_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuFile_2"));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(MainWindow);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("mainToolBar"));
        MainWindow->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusBar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        menuBar->addAction(menuFile_2->menuAction());
        menuFile_2->addAction(actionOpen);
        menuFile_2->addAction(actionClose);
        menuFile_2->addAction(actionExit);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", Q_NULLPTR));
        actionOpen->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Open", Q_NULLPTR));
        actionOpen->setShortcut(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Alt+0", Q_NULLPTR));
        actionClose->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Close", Q_NULLPTR));
        actionClose->setShortcut(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Alt+C", Q_NULLPTR));
        actionExit->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Exit", Q_NULLPTR));
        menuFile_2->setTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "File", Q_NULLPTR));
    } // retranslateUi

};
```

Comment: The code at a glance I see right, run make clean in the Build menu of QT Creator and then run qmake on the same menu or delete the build folder and compile your application back.

Comment: It doesn't work... I'm wondering if the word "Exit" has special meaning here? Cause when I change the "Exit" into "Exi t" can make it visiable again.

Comment: I have tried it and I have not had problems, you could share your project through drive, github or similar to be able to test it personally. A query has modified some of the generated files like the ui_Xxxx.h

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0SsWikldIBTUXVDU0pXZVRyNVU?usp=sharing

Comment: I have not had problems with the view, I have tried it in linux, there is only one error in your code: change `act->text() == 'Exit'` to `act->text() == "Exit"` but I think this has nothing to do with the view, look what I get: http://imgur.com/a/73Ui6

Comment: Well, if it works fine in your system, maybe this is cause by the conflict between QT and the Chinese Version of MacOS (some of my classmates also get the same problem). And really thank you for your help :)

Comment: Check the menu left to the "File" menu, the one with the applications name. Is it there? If yes, I can give you a full answer

Comment: Wow, I found it! Just inside the App menu, whose name has been changed into "Quit <APPNAME>". Thanks!!!